# How to use redis in Spark Streaming?

Tags: java, spark-streaming

I am using spark streaming in java.I configured sparkconfig obj as`SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp").setMaster("local[2]")
                .set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown","true")
                .set("redis.host", "localhost")
                .set("redis.port", "6379");`
and passing config obj in JavastreamingContext.

```
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.milliseconds(1000));
```

how can i access redis with jssc object.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This will create a stream from Redis list

```
  SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp").setMaster("local[2]")
            .set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true")
            .set("redis.host", "localhost")
            .set("redis.port", "6379");


    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.milliseconds(1000));

    RedisConfig redisConfig = new RedisConfig(new RedisEndpoint(sparkConf));

    RedisStreamingContext redisStreamingContext = new RedisStreamingContext(jssc.ssc());
    String[] keys = new String[]{"myList"};
    RedisInputDStream<Tuple2<String, String>> redisStream =
            redisStreamingContext.createRedisStream(keys, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY(), redisConfig);

    redisStream.print();

    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination();
```

Push some data to list:

```
LPUSH "myList" "aaaa"
LPUSH "myList" "bbbb"
```